# How to convert array into array of objects using .reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

How do you convert a multi-dimensional array into an array of objects using .reduce()?

Starting array

```
[
    [
        ['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]
    ],
    [
        ['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]
    ]
]
```

And ending array

```
[
    {juice: 'apple', maker: 'motts', price: 12},
    {juice: 'orange', maker: 'sunkist', price: 11}
]
```

This is what I have now. This is really just me shooting in the dark.

```
var transformData = (array) => {
    var newArray = array.push(function (all, item, index) {
        var newItem = item.reduce(function (all, item, index) {
            all[item[0]] = item[1]
            return all
        }, {})
        return all
    }, [])
    newArray.push(newItem)
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: you realise you're pushing functions onto the new array

Comment: try `array.map` instead of ` array.push(`

Comment: The odd thing is you think array.push works like array.reduce :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a combination of `array.map` and `array.reduce`.

`Array.push` is suited to add element to an array, but if you want to transform all elements of an array to a certain specification, its always better to use `array.map`

```js
var data = [
    [
        ['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]
    ],
    [
        ['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]
    ]
]

var result = data.map(function(list){
  return list.reduce(function(o, kv){
    o[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    return o;
  }, {});
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is great. I had something similar to this before, but I was using .reduce() in place of .map().

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for the properties with a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var data = [[['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]], [['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]]], 
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(...o.map(p => ({ [p[0]]: p[1] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Does `Object.assign(...o.map(` have any advantages over `array.reduce`?

Comment: I knew there was a better way :p by the way ... go all the way with ES2015++ - `.map(o => Object.assign(...o.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))))` (though, it does start looking like "brainf*ck" :p)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `reduce` and `foreach`.

```js
var items = [
    [
        ['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]
    ],
    [
        ['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]
    ]
];


var transformData = items.reduce((newArr, currArr) => {
  var obj = {};
  currArr.forEach((x) => {
    obj[x[0]] = x[1];
  });
  return newArr.concat(obj);
},[]);
console.log(transformData);
```

A solution using two reduce.

```js
var items = [
    [
        ['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]
    ],
    [
        ['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]
    ]
];


var transformData = items.reduce((newArr, currArr) => {
  return newArr.concat(currArr.reduce((o, arr) =>{
      o[arr[0]] = arr[1];
      return o;
   }, {}));  
},[]);
console.log(transformData);
```

Comment: You can also change it to reduce instead of forEach ```const obj = currArr.reduce((a,x) => {
    a[x[0]] = x[1];
    return a
  },{});```

Comment: Thanks @GerardBanasig updated the solution using two reduce. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're actually close, except you seem to think array.push works like array.reduce - it doesn't

```
var transformData = array => 
    array.map(subarray => 
        subarray.reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
            result[key] = value;
            return result;
        }, {})
    );
```

Since you're using some ES2015+ features, I used more ... the destructuring of the inner array [key, value]

I just have to add this "extension" to the best answer so far

```
const transformData=_=>_.map(_=>Object.assign(..._.map(([$,_])=>({[$]:_}))));
```

Try reading that in a few months and know what it's doing :p

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var parray=[
[
    ['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]
],
[
    ['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]
]
];

var newArray=[]
parray.forEach(function(data){
var cak  =  data.reduce(function(a, b) {
a[b[0]]=b[1]
  return a;
}, {})
newArray.push(cak)
})
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a succinct expression using `map` and `reduce` along with object spread syntax.

```js
const data = [
  [
    ['juice', 'apple'], ['maker', 'motts'], ['price', 12]
  ],
  [
    ['juice', 'orange'], ['maker', 'sunkist'], ['price', 11]
  ]
]

const data2 =
  data.map (pairs =>
    pairs.reduce ((o, [k,v]) =>
      ({ ...o, [k]: v }), {}))

console.log (data2)
```